# Oracle SQL query performance change when changing date predicate by one day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this very complex sql query with many joins that runs in a few seconds with one date in the predicate, but when I change the date by one day, I end up cancelling the query after 15 minutes.  PHA is the PO.PO_HEADERS_ALL table in Oracle, and the CREATION_DATE column is defined as type DATE.

```
--this finishes in a few seconds with 444 records
and pha.creation_date > to_date('23-JAN-2021','DD-MON-YYYY')

-- this never finishes
and pha.creation_date > to_date('22-JAN-2021','DD-MON-YYYY')
```

If use TRUNC(pha.creation_date) in the predicate, then both queries finish in a few seconds, with expected results.

Just wondering if someone can explain why one day would cause a difference?  The explain plans in TOAD did not really look any different between the two queries.

Comment: Without knowing the rest of the query, we can only guess.  My guess is that you have some joins that don't make sense under certain conditions, but those conditions don't exist with data after 2021-01-23, but do exist if the data includes the previous day.  What does, for example a simplified query behave like?  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PO.PO_HEADERS_ALL pha WHERE pha.creation_date > to_date('22-JAN-2021','DD-MON-YYYY')`?  Then what about if you add a little bit more of your "very complex sql query"?  Expand out from that table, a bit at a time, until you encounter the problematic behaviour.

Comment: one reason can be for that +1 day , you have a lot of rows that query has to return

Comment: You said "The explain plans in TOAD did not really look any different between the two queries."  But that sounds like they mean that they were indeed different.  What were those differences?

Comment: Can you get a Count for the rows that you have when the query runs in few seconds and when it takes more time.

Comment: Try to analyse real-time monitoring data and identity the real difference between operations and what's taking so much time with [`dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL_MONITOR.html#GUID-04851EB0-32AB-424C-91A1-65AD9220A690) (with format active, it is more readable) or access the same data in EM if it is installed. This is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/monitoring-database-operations.html#GUID-C941CE9D-97E1-42F8-91ED-4949B2B710BF) with many details.

Comment: Using the "trunc(pha.creation_date) >" syntax, both queries return 444 records.  There must not be any records for JAN 23.  I thought about peeling back the joins slowly to diagnose it, but since the trunc syntax works, just not worth it.  I was more curious at this point why just changing it by one day would make such a difference.   The explain plans have same structure and number of lines.  Cardinality values only differ by 1 on all lines, except for range scan on index CREATION_DATE, 3587 vs 3553.  This doesn't seem to explain one taking a few seconds and one not finishing.

Comment: Create partition by list where with dates, the problem would be you will have a lot of partitions.

Comment: "I thought about peeling back the joins slowly to diagnose it, but since the trunc syntax works, just not worth it." - You're either interested in diagnosing it or you're not.  Just because the `TRUNC()` looks okay and should be fine, the whole is still fubar.  Break it down and build it back up as per basic diagnositc / debugging practice, or don't.  But not debugging guarantees it won't be diagnosed, never mind fixed.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments.  I kept digging, and it turns out there was a blanket PO created on Jan 22 that added 11M records, so that was the straw that caused the issue.  But also the original syntax as provided by the user did not have the to_date function or the trunc function, just the "creation_date > '22-JAN-2021'", adding some confusion as to whether the Jan 22 PO was selected or not.

Comment: `creation_date > '22-JAN-2021'` is much the same as `float_value > 1`, although no time component is specified, it's implicit.  Just as `1 == 1.000000` so `'22-JAN-2021' == '22-JAN-2021 00:00:00.000'`  This means that your condition excludes midnight at the beginning of the day, but includes *everything* after that.